# sql connection string issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, connection-string

I want to connect to a remote database (SQL Server 2008) through code using a connection string. But I am not be able to connect to it. But I can connect the database using the SQL Server Management Studio successfully, using SQL Server authentication.

But whenever I am trying using code I am getting the exception like::

> [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Invalid Instance()).]Invalid connection.

My connection string is like this ::

```
Data Source=192.x.x.x;Initial Catalog=mydbName;User ID=user;Password=passw;provider=SQLOLEDB
```

Can anybody help me out.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are Firewalls correctly set on the server? Are you using valid credentials? How does your code look like? Make sure the remote connections are set to TCP/IP. (Found under Sql Server Configuration Manager)

Comment: What is the application where you're using this connection string? The last part (`provider=SQLOLEDB`) shouldn't be there if you're doing this from .NET...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't show the C# code you're using to connect - but I think the problem is the provider. If ever possible - use the **native** SQL client interface from the `System.Data.SqlClient` assembly to connect to SQL Server.

Can you try this connection string instead:

```
Data Source=192.x.x.x;Initial Catalog=mydbName;User ID=user;Password=passw;
```

In your config:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
     <add name="MyConnStr"
          connectionString="Data Source=192.x.x.x;Initial Catalog=mydbName;User ID=user;Password=passw;" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

And then use this code snippet:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnStr"].ConnectionString;

using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   ....
}
```

See the [Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com) web site for **tons** of examples of valid connection strings and what all those options mean.

Comment: thanks you link works perfectly i got the answer,i need to mention the ip,port to connect my remote database.

This Help Me ::
Data Source=190.190.200.100,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;

Comment: The port shouldn't really be necessary if it's 1433 (or a named instance *and* the browser service is running). Are you sure the fix wasn't simply removing the `Provider=` portion? Did you try the new connection string without the port specifier?

Comment: @AaronBertrand ,i removed the Provider but it still showing error,also when i was try to write the System.Data.SqlClient in front of provider its also showing the error.But Ip and Port combination work perfectly in my case.thanks for every response. cheers :)